# Как получить ссылки на видеофайлы со стены ВКонтакте?

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я использую этот [SDK](https://github.com/thest1/Android-VKontakte-SDK) и хочу получить ссылки на файл видео из стены.

```
ArrayList arrayList = api.getWallMessages(owner_id, 1, 0, null);
WallMessage message = (WallMessage)arrayList.get(0);
ArrayList attachments = message.attachments;
Attachment attachment = (Attachment)attachments.get(0);
Video video = attachment.video;
```

На выходе получаю обьект `video`, вот только поля `external,mp4_360,mp4_480...` = null. Я что-то делаю не так, или нужно сделать свое приложение доверенным, написав об этом в поддержку ВК?  
Спасибо!